# Медведь или ведмедь?

Tags: этимология

Прочитав предыдущий вопрос о названиях животных, хочу задать свой.
Как я понимаю, слово "медведь" происходит от слов "мед" и "ведать", то есть, "знающий, где есть мед". Но в украинском языке это слово звучит как "ведмiдь". То есть (исключая замену Е на I), буквы В и М меняются местами, что, впрочем, практически не отражается на смысле слова.
Очень интересно было бы узнать, откуда такая игра букв и как было изначально?

Comment: Насчёт украинского: нам бы со своими словами разобраться... ===== Для справки: по словарям ЦСЯ погреб для варёного и питейного мёда называли медушей, а кладовую для мёда — медвеницей. Интересно, что даже намёка на бытование слов медведь/медведица в них нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно считается, что медведь — это *ведающий мед*, но есть и другое мнение: медведь — медоед, то есть он не ведает мед, а просто ест его.

Слово известно с XI в., и его следует считать сложением основ medv — медовый и edъ — еда, пища (сравнить *медвяный*, medvьnъ и [о.-с.] *медовый*). Таким образом, *В* входит в первую основу.

Интересно, что слово известно в разных славянских языках (польском, болгарском, словенском), но только в украинском  слове *ведмiдь* переставлены основы.

Это фонетическое явление относится к комбинаторным изменениями фонем и называется **метатеза** (перестановка фонем, от греч. metathesis), например:  ведмедь/медведь, тарелка/Teller (нем.), Фрол/flor (лат.), ладонь/долонь, футляр/Futteral (нем.)

Комбинаторные и позиционные изменения: 
http://www.wddb.ru/publ/jazykoznanie/foneticheskie_processy/12-1-0-368

Comment: "..medv - медовый и edъ - еда.."  
Зачем такие сложности? "измеряющий землю" - "землемер", "летающий самостоятельно" - "самолёт", "ходящий быстро" - "скороход"... Не знаю, как в других языках, а в русском корень, обозначающий действие, в сложных словах ставится вторым.

Comment: Ну так "едящий мёд" - "медоед"/"медведь", то бишь корень, означающий действие, тоже второй.

Comment: "..medv - медовый и edъ - еда.." - это, скорее, "медовая еда" ("едящий медовый" - как-то не по-русски).

Comment: А как по русски - медедь? Как-то очень на глагол похоже, фонетически неясное слово. Также сравним: снедь вместо едь, то есть перед Е характерно наличие согласного. Кстати, существует настоящий медоед - животное из семейства куньих.

Comment: **greydog**, в словах "муравьед", "людоед" морфема "ед" обозначает именно действие: едящий муравьев, едящий людей. Почему в слове "медведь" вы считаете, что "ед" обозначает существительное?

Comment: @Пересвет, "..medv - медовый.." В словах "муравьед" и "людоед" "муравей" и "люди" - существительные.
____

@София, "медоед", но не "медвоед". "В" в Вашем варианте разбора указывает на прилагательное "медовый/медвяный". А к нему "в пару" идёт не наречие "едящий", а существительное "еда".

Comment: Медоед, муравьед и людоед. Исходное словосочетание: есть мед, муравьев и людей. Способ образования: суффиксальное сложение основ,форманты: соединительная гласная, нулевой суффикс. В качестве второй основы использована глагольная основа настоящего времени ед/ят.

Comment: "Медоед", но не "мед**в**оед". Если "в", __как Вы писали__, принадлежит первой основе, то она образована не от существительного "мёд", а от **прилагательного** "медовый/медвяный". И требует не глагола ("ед/ят"), а существительного ("еда"?).  
Именно по этой причине я считаю Ваш вариант "разбора" ошибочным.

Comment: Во-первых, прилагательное может быть и субстантивированное. Во-вторых, есть производные существительные от мёда с суффиксом -в-: медовик и медовуха. Вполне возможно, что одно из этих слов или какое-то другое уже было в то время и стало основой для создания "медведя". В-третьих, -в- может быть и протетической согласной.