# Каким способом образовано слово "медведь"?

Tags: словообразование

Слово ***медведь***, как известно, трудное для этимологии. Ест он мёд или ведает мёд — понять сложно. [Медведь или ведмедь?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/39521/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C)

Но в любом случае предполагается, что слово  состоит из двух основ.

Тогда можно ли на примере этого слова прояснить вопрос  о происхождении соединительных гласных, по которому у лингвистов нет единого мнения (фонетический, морфемный или соединительный элемент?) ) и составить возможные словообразовательные модели?

Из учебника старославянского языка: **медвѣдь (дословно "медоед").**

Answer (score 2):

По Цыганенко и Фасмеру,современная форма сущ. медведь развилась из *meduědis, образованного сложением и.-е. слов *mеdus <мед> и * ěd-is <едящий> (есть). Звук у перед  ě стал звучать как v [в]. Слово медведь как табу у многих славян вытеснило более старое и.-е. название этого зверя *(a)rktos (в укр. ведмидь- тожд. i из е в закрытом слоге и перестановка компонентов слова). http://www.slovorod.ru/etym-cyganenko/cyg-m.htm

Н.М.Шанский поддерживает эту версию:  Сложение медв < medu и едь < ědь (см. мед, еда), u перед ě > в. (этимологический онлайн-словарь Шанского Н. М.)

Следовательно, это не сложение основ, а сложение слов, т.е. сращение (слияние), поэтому здесь нет соединительной гласной

Comment: А Черных считает,  что  звук V относится к первой основе medvьnъ (медвяный), поэтому соединительная гласная вроде бы должна быть.

Comment: Это не противопоставлено мнению Цыганенко и Фасмера. Медвяный - это медовый, просто перед суфф.-ян- звучит В вместо У. (медуяный = медвяный). Производящая основа меду=медв. Старое слово медведь, новое медоед. Вот в новом О - соединительная гласная. мед/о/ед - это сложное слово, а медведь - всё слово корень, сложным его можно считать только этимологически,  образовано оно когда-то слиянием слова и части основы. Иллюстрировать этим словом словообразовательную модель сложения основ с соединительным гласным, думаю,  некорректно.